# How to apply conditions to vlookup values from another file where there are multiple values between two dates?

Tags: excel

I have a list of employees id, their employment start date, their employment end date in one file. Another file has their Groups like FT, PT, CS etc with scattered start date and end dates with multiple groups between a specific employee start date and end date.
Dor example -

```
Employee ID 10 | Employment Start Date 01/01/2011 | Employment  End Date 12/31/2018
```

Group file consists:

```
Employee ID 10 | Group Start Date 01/01/2011 | Group End Date 12/31/2015 - Group PT
Employee ID 10 | Group Start Date 01/01/2016 | Group End Date 12/31/2017 - Group FT
Employee ID 10 | Group Start Date 01/01/2018 | Group End Date 12/31/2018 - Group FT
```

I need to ignore PT and get FT to have this:

```
Employee ID | Employment Start Date  | Employment  End Date | Group
10            01/01/2011              12/31/2018              FT
```

How do I get it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Employee ID:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1,1)-2),"Employee ID ",""))
```

Group Start Date:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("|",A1,1)+2,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,1)+2)-FIND("|",A1,1)-3),"Group Start Date ","")
```

Group End Date:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,1)+2)+2,FIND(" - ",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,1)+2)+3)-FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,1)+2)-2),"Group End Date ", "")
```

Group (FT/PT):

```
=RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Just use the filter functionality to filter out PT employees.